# How do I test a virtual property on an abstract class with Rhino Mocks and MSpec?

Tags: testing, virtual, rhino-mocks, mspec

I have a virtual property, `FirstName`, on an abstract class, `Foo`. I need to test the  virtual property's behavior. The method never fires when this test executes (and so the test always fails, no matter what's in the method's body). How can I make this method my system under test?  How can I test this method?

```cs
[Subject(typeof(Foo))]
public class When_whatever 
{
    Establish context = () => 
    {
        _fooSut = _mockRepository.PartialMock<Foo>(argumentOne, argumentTwo);
    };

    Because of = () => _result = _fooSut.FirstName;

    It should_return_not_null = () => _result.ShouldNotBeNull();

    private static string _result;
    private static Foo _fooSut;
}
```

I'm using Rhino Mocks 3.5 and mspec.

Comment: Code formatting seems not to be working.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tried `PartialMock` feature? [See here](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: We used PartialMock to create _fooSut (I've updated the code to show that).

Comment: We were doing something incorrectly, I think, with the Rhino Mocks 3.5 partial mocks syntax.  We've upgraded to Rhino Mocks 3.6, which offers a static context for creating partial mocks, and we've successfully executed/tested the virtual method of the abstract class using partial mocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `_mockRepository.ReplayAll()` before using mock. But in this case it should be just executed. 
BTW what behavior do you want to test? 
I don't think that having abstract public property is a good design. Could you post your `Foo` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

### How to Build a Partial Mock

You're creating a partial mock, a mock that implements the abstract class and provides mock capabilities for virtual and abstract parts of the class.

```
_fooSut = _mockRepository.PartialMock<Foo>(argumentOne, argumentTwo);
```

And you're calling the property that you said was *virtual*, `FirstName`.

```
_result = _fooSut.FirstName;
```

But, you're not stubbing the virtual call, so it's returning the default value! In this case, `null`. You would need to add this call to your context.

```
_fooSut.Stub(x => x.FirstName).Return("Lance");
```

### How to Test Behavior

Lance, I'm going to parrot [the_joric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681962/rhino-mocks-how-to-test-virtual-method-on-abstract-class/6691532#6691532)'s question... *what is the behavior you're trying to test*? The test you are writing above is only testing that you can setup a mock.

I can only begin to guess how you're implementing concrete classes for this abstract. So, maybe what you want to do is test that every implementation provides a non-null value for this property? In which case, you would want to use a [behavior](http://jagregory.com/writings/behaviours-in-mspec/).

```
[Behaviors]
public class ConcreteFoo
{
    It should_set_a_non_null_first_name = () => _fooSut.FirstName.ShouldNotBeNull();

    protected static Foo _fooSut;
}
```

And each implementation of `Foo` can be tested against those behaviors.

```
[Subject(typeof(DefaultFoo))]
public class When_using_a_default_foo
{
    Behaves_like<ConcreteFoo> a_concrete_impl_of_foo;

    protected static DefaultFoo _fooSut = new DefaultFoo();
}

[Subject(typeof(CustomFoo))]
public class When_using_a_custom_foo
{
    Behaves_like<ConcreteFoo> a_concrete_impl_of_foo;

    protected static CustomFoo _fooSut = new CustomFoo();
}
```